# Render 3d view using EarthEngine using parameters like in EarthStudio to simulate real environments

Tags: google-earth, 3d, google-earth-api

In Google Earth Studio, it is possible to create animations on Google Earth using 3d imagery using the following parameters: latitude, longitude, altitude as well as camera pan and tilt. This means that it is possible to get renders of 3d environments in Earth.

I am developing an aerial simulation which requires such simulation data but it is not possible for me to manually collect it or sustainably take screenshots from Earth. Is there an API which allows me to pass in these parameters, producing a render?

Here is an example image (I attribute this completely to EarthStudio) and the parameters required:

[image]

Latitude: 51.505385202081,
Longitude: -0.1220879043863,
Altitude: 118.99m

Camera Pan: 126.27556729083472 deg,
Camera Tilt: 78.39171328968358 deg

How can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The desktop version of Google Earth Pro can produce animations.  Under Tools -> Movie Maker.

You can make a KML tour using your parameters and export the viewport as an mp4 or a sequence of PNGs or JPGs.

Comment: Also, in case it helps, in Google Earth for web (https://earth.google.com/web/), you can set the view parameters in the URL, so you could construct URLs of your desired views and open them automatically.  But would still require screenshots to capture the image.

Comment: Is it possible just to get the individual image? Also, @ChristiaanAdams, is it possible to even specify camera view and tilt parameters on the web version?

Comment: Look at the parameters in the URL after the @ symbol. The first two are just numbers for longitude and latitude of the view target (place camera/eye is looking at).  Then the one ending in "a" should be altitude of the view target, and the one ending in "d" should be distance of the eye/camera from the view target. The next ends in "y", and I don't recall what it's for, maybe something about field of view? Then there are three ending in "h", "t" and "r" for heading, tilt and roll.  Note that this is not an officially supported API, so it could change at any time in the future.